# VBA Insert Column Header & Fill Formula on Column

Tags: excel, vba

```
'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example

Dim lastRow As Long


With Worksheets("Summary")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'Inserts column on E
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

'Titles header "Net Return"
Range("E3").FormulaR1C1 = "Net Return"
'Places formula in cell E4
Range("E4").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-3]"
'Fills formula down row - this is where my code breaks
Range("E4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E4:(lastRow - 1)"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I want to insert new column on E, input the formula =(C4-B4) in cell E4 and fill down until lastRow.  How can I utilize lastRow when declaring the range of cells to populate my formula in?  I receive runtime error 1004 on my .Autofill line.

Comment: What is the "last row" in a brand-new empty column?  How is that to be determined?

Comment: Good point, I suppose my method won't work then unless it determines last row based upon column A, which will always have the maximum number of rows.  I can perform a last row check on column A and subtract one from it and store that in lastRow?  I am unsure how that code looks

Comment: Why not just `Range(Cells(4,5), Cells(lastRow-1, 5)).FillDown`?  Or, even, skip that step and just do it in one: `Range("E4:E" & (lastRow-1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-3]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Sub SetUpSummarySheet()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Summary")

    InsertWithHeaderAndFormula ws, "E", "Net Return", "=RC[-2]-RC[-3]"
    InsertWithHeaderAndFormula ws, "G", "Blah", "=RC[-1]"
    'etc for other solumns

End Sub

'Insert a column in sheet ws, add a header hdr and a formula sForm to extend
'   as far down as there are values in ColA
Sub InsertWithHeaderAndFormula(ws As Worksheet, colLetter As String, _
                                hdr As String, sForm As String)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Cells(1, colLetter).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    ws.Cells(3, colLetter).Value = hdr
    ws.Cells(4, colLetter).Resize(lastRow - 3, 1).FormulaR1C1 = sForm

End Sub
```

Comment: Not so tricky so I'm sure you will figure it out.  Any time you find yourself coding repetitive actions with a few variable pieces, it can likely be factored out into a standalone sub you can just pass the variable items into.

Comment: I will have to save your answer in a text document for future reference.  Quick question: I can just keep inserting the other columns in SetUpSummarySheet() and it will sorta loop through it in the next sub?

Comment: Yes just follow the same pattern for the remaining columns you want to insert

Comment: How can this combination of subs be called from a main sub?

Comment: You'd just call `SetUpSummarySheet`